# NoCredentialProviders error with awslogs logging driver in docker at mac

Tags: docker, logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Hi I am trying to enable cloud watch logging in my docker container on my mac machine.
Docker version .

Version:      18.03.1-ce . 
API version:  1.37 .

I am getting following error every-time i start container

```
Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

I have tried following approaches:

- Exporting AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (etc.) in /etc/default/docker
- mounted  ~/.aws/credentials
- Passing aws credentials as env

But every-time i get same error.

```
docker run -d -p 5801:8080 --env AWS_REGION=us-west-2  -v /Users/me/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-west-2 --log-opt awslogs-group=perf-log-group --log-opt awslogs-create-group=true --log-opt awslogs-stream=awslogs-ing imageId
```

Could you please suggest what i am missing here as if i remove log part application works fine and i am able access aws api in application.

Comment: I have the same problem right now

Answer (score 1):

I came here searching the net for an answer as I was not capable to understand what the docs want me to do, too. Finally this tutorial helped me make my way through it: https://transang.me/configure-docker-to-send-log-to-aws/. Although I am on an Ubuntu 20.04 I assume we both face the same trouble to understand where to put the env information

You will have to provide the credentials that shall be used to the docker daemon of your local machine, not to the `docker build` or the docker run command.

according to the tutorial put the config here:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
[Service] 
Environment="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my-aws-access-key"
Environment="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my-secret-access-key"
```

followed by the commands

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

to flush the changes and reload the docker daemon or stop and feed the environment variables directly to the daemon:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop docker
$ sudo env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my-aws-access-key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my-secret-access-key /usr/bin/dockerd
```

Pitfall: If you have MFA enabled you may need to provide the security token, too (at least I stumbled over it) than the daemon invocation becomes:

```
$ sudo env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN /usr/bin/dockerd
```