# Docker Windows: awslogs logging driver - NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am using Docker on Windows (Docker Desktop).

I have a `docker-compose.yml` on which I want to enable `awslogs` logging driver:

```
version: "3"
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0
        container_name: zookeeper
        hostname: zookeeper
        ports:
          - "2181:2181"
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
            ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
            AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options:
                awslogs-region: eu-west-1
                awslogs-group: zookeeper-logs
```

Under `%userprofile%\.aws` I have valid, working aws credentials:

```
/C:\Users\catalin.gavan\.aws
├── config
└── credentials
```

When I try to build and run the containers, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\catalin.gavan\Work\DockerApp>
docker-compose up

Creating network "dockerapp_default" with the default driver
Creating zookeeper ... error                                                                                                                                                              
ERROR: for zookeeper  Cannot start service zookeeper: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

ERROR: for zookeeper  Cannot start service zookeeper: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The CloudWatch `zookeeper-logs` logs group already exists. The AWS profile which I am using has full access, and has already been tested with different scenarios.

The problem seems to be caused by Docker Desktop (Windows) daemon, which cannot read the `.aws` credentials.

The same problem has been reported:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/awslogs-logging-driver-issue-nocredentialproviders-no-valid-providers-in-chain/91135
- [NoCredentialProviders error with awslogs logging driver in docker at mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142771/nocredentialproviders-error-with-awslogs-logging-driver-in-docker-at-mac)
- [Awslogs logging driver issue - NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838429/awslogs-logging-driver-issue-nocredentialproviders-no-valid-providers-in-chai)

Comment: Where you able to figure it out? Can you please share the solution?

Comment: Hi @OSGIJava. Unfortunately I think this feature is not supported on Docker Windows. Check this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9684#issuecomment-738130127). Eventually I created a Virtual-Machine on which I installed Ubuntu and I followed the steps described on the link pasted by Atul Sharma

Answer (score -1):

It's important to remember that this credential file needs to be made available to the docker engine not the client. It's the engine (the daemon) that is going to connect to aws.

If you create that file as a user, it may not be available to the engine. If you're running docker-machine and the engine is in the VM, you'll need to move that credentials file into the VM for the root user.

Here's how you can pass credentials to daemon https://wdullaer.com/blog/2016/02/28/pass-credentials-to-the-awslogs-docker-logging-driver-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I am working with Docker Desktop (Windows). I don't know how/if the aws credentials are passed to the Docker daemon. The daemon starts/runs automatically. I also tried restarting the Docker Desktop service...but no success. The tutorial from above is for Linux...and It doesn't help me that much